# Qt/c++ : start a process if this process is not running

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have wrote an app in Qt/c++, The app is currently checking some state and start a new process in case the statement become true.

I'm able to start the new process when the statement is true but the app will have to periodically check the statement through a timer. I want to make sure that in case the statement become true and and stay at true I will not start the application multiple times.

here is the current code

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->startDetached(fileBrowserExecutablePath);
```

I know the process can be checked using

```
process->state() == QProcess::NotRunning
```

but to check this I need first to start the process otherwise process don't know what to check. I mean which process to check.

Any idea on how to check the process ?

I have tried to init the process with the application I want to start but it failed to build.

Something like :

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(fileBrowserExecutablePath);
```

Thanks

Comment: `QProcess *p = new QProcess; qDebug() << (p->state() == QProcess::NotRunning);` prints `true`. Why is this bad?

Comment: for such behaviour i use a python script (could be anything tho) that parses the list of all running processes and starts the executable when not running

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Can you modify this other application?

Comment: QProcess::startDetached is a static method and doesn't modify `process` at all. Use start() if you want to monitor/control the process after starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Qt(if you didn't create the process with `QProcess` earlier, of course). You have to use a platform specific API to check if the process is running.

---

But if you did start the process then you can use the `QProcess` object to check its state.
You do it like this:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->start(fileBrowserExecutablePath);
///...
p->state() == QProcess::Running
```

That way you can use the `process` object to check the state. But note, that if you don't have the `process` object than you have to use the native API to check if the process is running.